# Set up file share with automatic mount using NFS

Tags: mount, nfs, fstab

Here's the problem: I wanted to create a file share between my laptop and my pc at home so that I have access to my files from both machines. The `laptop` is the server (as I might need the files when on the move) and the `pc` is the client.

Here's my attempt at a solution: having linux (debian) on both machines, I decided to use NFS. Everything worked fine until I rebooted both machines and I ran into a catch-22. Ideally, I wanted the server to automatically mount the NFS, so I added a line in `/etc/fstab`. Although, after rebooting the server, I noticed that I had to re-run `exportfs -a` to re-load my `/etc/exports`, which looks like this:

```
/nfs     pc(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

In order to do this, though, `pc` had to be reachable, otherwise I got this error upon

```
exportfs: failed to resolve pc
```

So, if `pc` had to be reachable before `laptop` was on, it defies the point of having a `/etc/fstab` for `pc`, unless I expected very few re-boots of `laptop`, which is not my case.

In short: `pc` wants `laptop` to be reachable to mount the NFS automatically via fstab, while `laptop` wants `pc` to be reachable in order to assign the correct permissions in exports. Is there a way to run `exportfs -a` at startup for `laptop` without having to have `pc` on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server shouldn't care if the client is reachable or not.  It's just making a share available... whether it's used or not.

The error you are getting "exportfs: failed to resolve pc", isn't saying it can't "reach" pc.  It's saying it cant "resolve" pc.  The problem is that you are referencing a specific client by hostname, but the system can't resolve the hostname into an IP address.

Apparently, this is a known bug in the way exportfs works.  I haven't' looked too deep into it, but in the cases I saw (simply google for the error message), it's a timing problem between when nfs starts and when dns services are available.  There are also problems with DHCP defined clients and DNS not being updated fast enough.

Anyway, your problem is a name-resolution one.  If "pc" has a static IP address, you could use the address in /etc/exports, or add "pc" to your /etc/hosts file.  If either hosts are DHCP, you may be out of luck.

On the client side ("pc"), you might want to look into using automounter (autofs) to mount the remote filesystem instead of using /etc/fstab.  Automounter will only mount the filesystem when you need it, so it's unlikely to hang on a system boot if the NFS server isn't available.

Some references to the problems with exportfs and name resolution:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860264
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=69981
Lot's more out there showing similar problem.

Comment: Great tips, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to solve it with the nfs-server.service unit but did not succeed.
So I finally ended up to put a script into crontab, like

```
#crontab -e
@reboot /usr/local/bin/exportNFS
```

and

```
#cat /usr/local/bin/exportNFS
sleep 5
/usr/sbin/exportfs -r
```